# get_the_title outputs title until spacing; it does not get full length of title

Tags: query-posts, get-posts, title, get-the-title

If I have a post with a spacing in it (like: Hello World), than `get_the_title` shows me only "Hello" as a link and not the whole permalink. I already tried using a `substring` to get it done, but it did not work out for me. Am I missing here something?

I just used `get_the_title();` and put it in a variable.

Code:

```
<?php
$titletest = get_the_title();

echo " <a href=http://www.testungsss.com/search?q=$titletest>$titletest</a> ";
?>
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: There is not much to show really. I updated my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title isn't correctly encoded for use in a query variable. Try this:

```
echo ' <a href="http://www.testungsss.com/search?q=' . urlencode($titletest) . '">' . $titletest . '</a>';
```